# Save changes to database vaadin

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, vaadin, save

I have an application which has a table and when you click on an item in the table it fills in a group of textfields with its data (FieldGroup), and then you have the option of saving the changes **I was wondering how would I save the changes the user makes to my postgres database**.  I am using vaadin and hibernate for this application.  So far I  have tried to do

```
   editorField.commit() // after the user clicks the save button
```

I have tried

```
   editorField.commit() 
   hbsession.persist(editorField) //hbsession is the name of my Session
```

and I have also tried

```
   editorField.commit();
   hbsession.save(editorField);
```

The last two ones give me the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
```

Comment: why don't you try jpacontainer addon?

Comment: when you use hibernate and vaadin you will need to use the entitymanager-per-request pattern. look for it in the book of vaadin

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without JPAContianer because Hibernate already made all of my bean classes and xml files, Is it possible to do it with BeanItemContainer?

Comment: sure you can get it done with beanitemcounter, but I recommend you to immediatelly drop all your xml files, use jpa2 with annotations and use jpacontainer. The time you will use to learn it will multiply enormeously in productivity as you get used to it

Comment: Thanks for the advice before I do the switch would using JPAContainer affect my Bean and xml files created by Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to make changes to the database here is some code to demonstrate:

```
try {
  /** define the session and begin it **/
  hbsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  hbsession.beginTransaction();

  /** table is the name of the Bean class linked to the corresponding SQL table **/
  String query = "UPDATE table SET name = " + textfield.getValue();

  /** Run the string as an SQL query **/
  Query q = hbsession.createQuery(query);
  q.executeUpdate(); /** This command saves changes or deletes a entry in table **/

  hbsession.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (RuntimeException rex) {
    hbsession.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw rex;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first thing you need to realize is Vaadin differs from conventional request/response web framework. Actually, **Vaadin is **event driven**** framework very similar to Swing. It builds a application context from very first click of the user and holds it during whole website visit. The problem is there is no entry request point you can start hibernate session and no response point to close. There are tons of requests during a single click on button.

So, *entitymanager-per-request* pattern is completely useless. It is better to use one standalone em or *em-per-session* pattern with hibernate.connection_release after_transaction to keep connection pool low.

To the JPAContianer, it is not usable as far you need to refresh the container or you have to handle beans with relations. Also, I did not manage to get it working with batch load, so every reading of entry or relation equals one select to DB. Do not support lazy loading.

All you need is open EM/session. Try to use suggested patters or open EM/session every transaction and merge your bean first.

Your question is quite complex and hard to answer, but I hope these links help you get into:

**Pojo binding strategy for hibernate**

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/39712

**MVP-lite**

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/mvp-lite (stick with event driven pattern)

Comment: Not sure about this answer... The book of vaadin explicity tells you to use entitymanager-per-request pattern