# Vaadin 7 UI session gets closed prematurely

Tags: java, session, web, vaadin, vaadin7

In my current project, that is based on `Vaadin 7.6.2`, I get an error that I simply don't find an explanaition for in my code. In this application, I open up a bunch of EntityManagers for a UI session and then close them when the session is detatched (when `UI.detatch()` is called). Now my problem is that my log clearly states that the session is detatched and then used again. AFAIK this should not happen, right?

Here is an excerp from the log file:

```
***  || 29.02.2016 09:59:32:504 | SESSION BEC3759B529AC42AA7FFE62314633979 | USER a******.i**** | de.darkblue.bagheera.db.EntityManagerBeanFactory.closeAll()
     || Closed 3 entity managers for session a******.i****

***  || 29.02.2016 09:59:32:504 | SESSION BEC3759B529AC42AA7FFE62314633979 | USER a******.i**** | de.darkblue.bagheera.BagheeraUI.detach()
     || Session de.darkblue.bagheera.BagheeraUI@1c5c5ab2 was detatched.

[...]
     
!!!! || 29.02.2016 10:00:21:159 | SESSION BEC3759B529AC42AA7FFE62314633979 | USER a******.i**** | com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler.doDefault()
     ||  caused by:
     || java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager.
     ||         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.verifyOpenWithSetRollbackOnly(EntityManagerImpl.java:1934)
     ||         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:2569)
     ||         at de.darkblue.bagheera.ui.tab.EditActivityReportTab.isOverlappingEntry(EditActivityReportTab.java:383)
     ||         [...]
```

You can see that the session `BEC3759B529AC42AA7FFE62314633979` was closed at `09:59:32:504` but then reused nearly one minute later. I was under the impression that when `UI.detatch()` was called (as in log line 2), the UI instance was not used anymore, becuase the session expired (due to three mission heartbeats)? I get the feeling that I have the wrong idea about the lifecycle of a Vaadin UI session. It would be nice if someone could help me shed some light on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what session you are printing and referring to there.

I think you know this but you have the `HttpSession` holds a `VaadinSession` object which hold multiple `UI` objects.  If any of that sounds interesting, I think you'll find this helpful - [how to put data in session variable and get the data in different page in vaadin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439761/how-to-put-data-in-session-variable-and-get-the-data-in-different-page-in-vaadin).

But, my feeling is that you'll want to rethink your `EntityManager` lifecycle - see https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/jpacontainer/jpacontainer-hibernate.html

Although, others do advocate an *EM-per-session* approach such as seen here - [Save changes to database vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624438/save-changes-to-database-vaadin/17846489#17846489).

This all said, the same `VaadinSession` can absolutely be used for multiple UIs, in fact you'll see a map called `uIs` in `VaadinSession`.  Now, you do seem to get a new `VaadinSession` per browser window, but it isn't hard to instantiate multiple `UI` objects from the same window, and they will share the same `VaadinSession`.

Finally it is worth noting that most normal setups will also have single `HttpSession` across all windows in a browser instance.

Comment: Ah okay, that shed some light on it. I was under the impression that a vaadin session means a cookie-backed session for basically one browser connection (until the browser is closed). But your answer suggests a completely different approach.

Comment: So now that I read your answer more thoroughly, I think I now understand the problem: I attached all my EMs to a UI when instead I should have attached them to the session. I did not realize that UI and Session are two different things - I saw them as one. Thanks for your answer!