# Vaadin and db connection pooling

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, vaadin

I am new to the Vaadin framework and unsure on how to proceed about database connection.

What I don't want is to instatiate connection at each session. In my understading though, vaadin works at session level.

Is it possible to create a class which will persist no matter sessions, and then, vaadin session will query it to get the database connection?

Comment: I am going through the JPAcontainer tutorial, but I have to control the connection retrieved, I cannot trust some mid-layer to retrieve it, is this making the question clearer? thanks in advance

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527049/vaadin-jpacontainer-jdbc-connection-usage/17876743#17876743. It might help you.

Comment: You really should not create a database connection per session. Get a connection from the pool, use it, close it (which returns it to the pool) for the size of a single unit of work (usually within a single request, spanning multiple requests is not advisable). That way you can usually make do with just a few connections for a few hundred users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jdbc connection pool in your application server.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin in just a technology to create UI layer of your application, it has nothing to do with jdbc connections - your service layer should take care of business logic implementation, including working with your DB. This is the typical layering for web application. As per my understanding of your question, one of options will be to use Spring as your backend - it is pretty good in managing various types of data sources and related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vaadin and getting database are orthogonal issues, not really related to one another.

## `DataSource` interface

Usually best to define a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object for your particular database.

Take for example the [*H2 Database Engine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) and its [`DataSource` implementation](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html).

```
// Setup the data source.
JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:˜/test");
ds.setUser("sa");
ds.setPassword("sa");
return ds ; // Return as a `DataSource` object rather than concrete class.
```

Study your particular [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to find its likely implementation(s) of `DataSource`. For example, the [JDBC driver for Postgres](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) by postgresql.org [provides](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/datasource.html) `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource` (pooled) and `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource` (non-pooled).

Then ask that object for a database connection when you need to talk with the database. When done with that database operation, close the connection.

```
Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
```

You can use Java [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to do so simply.

```
try (
    Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
) 
{
    …
    // Use `conn` object to work with database.
    // When going out of scope here, the connection's `close` method is automatically called.
}
```

Some people highly recommend using [connection pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). I do *not* recommend connection pooling, except to remedy a proven problem. Connection pooling is surprisingly tricky to get right, with several notoriously failed projects, and still other projects that do not even recommend themselves for production use. And even if implemented well, connection pooling always brings additional issues such as connections returned to the pool in bad condition such as a transaction left hanging open. Starting with a fresh connection each time is the safest route. Some people decry the expense of obtaining fresh database connections. But I have not seen evidence of that expense in either my own experience or presented by others objectively with formal testing.

If you nevertheless decide to use pooling, your `DataSource` implementation can handle the pool behind the scenes. So the code and concepts discussed in this Answer hold for both pooled and non-pooled data source objects. That is the point of the `DataSource` interface, to mask over differences such as pooled versus non-pooled. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html).

## `ServletContext` and “attributes”

The issue then becomes where to store your `DataSource` object. Here is where Vaadin comes into the picture.

Vaadin is based on [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) (formerly known as Java Servlet) technology. Actually, Vaadin is one big servlet. Your Vaadin web runs on a server capable of hosting servlets. That server is required to support the [Jakarta Servlet specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/). That spec requires support for a [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object that represents your entire running web app. One "context" has zero, one, or more "session" objects  currently running your web app, one session per user per web browser.

Where it gets interesting for our purpose is that `ServletContext` provides a cache for any objects you might want to keep around to be available to all the sessions (users) of your app. This cache is known as "attributes", a key-value collection where the key is a `String`. You could store your `DataSource` here with something like `"javax.sql.DataSource"` as the key.

So how to get access to the `ServletContext` object representing our web app? See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59550032/642706) for explanation and possibly better approaches.

```
ServletContext servletContext = 
        VaadinServletService            // com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletService
        .getCurrentServletRequest()     // Returns a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        .getServletContext()            // Returns a `javax.servlet.ServletContext`. 
;
```

Now we can store our `DataSource` implementation object. We can use any `String` as long as it is distinct within the key-value collection. Tip: Prefix your key strings with your own domain name to ensure uniqueness.

```
servletContext.setAttribute( "com.example-javax.sql.DataSource" , dataSource ) ;
```

And retrieval by any code needing access to the database. The key-value collection stores the value as an `Object`, so we must cast.

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) servletContext.getAttribute( "com.example-javax.sql.DataSource" ) ;
```

Tip: You should probably test for NULL result.

## Your points

> What I don't want is to instatiate connection at each session.

No, you do not want to create a database connection per session, not normally. Maintaining an open database connection ties up resources on both the client and the server (memory, CPU, ports, etc.).

When you need to do database work, ask your `DataSource` object for a `Connection`. When done with the database, call `Connection::close` or let try-with-resources syntax do so automatically.

> In my understading though, vaadin works at session level.

Vaadin is just a Jakarta Servlet. And servlets are just web apps that delegate most of the HTTP and web work to a web container such as Tomcat or Jetty or Glassfish etc.

Part of common web work is to create the illusion of a stateful connection despite HTTP’s stateless request-response architecture. Cookies or other tricks are used to track a single user between multiple requests. A Servlet-based web container handles this on our behalf as web app programmers, creating objects to track each user as a "session". And there is nothing special about Vaadin in this regard.

> Is it possible to create a class which will persist no matter sessions, and then, vaadin session will query it to get the database connection?

Vaadin and database connections are two topics not directly related to one another.

I suggest you do some more study to get really clear on basic Web technology to understand how HTTP requests/responses work, and how sessions create the illusion of stateful connections. This applies to all web work, not just Vaadin. Vaadin builds upon this foundation, so to understand Vaadin you need to understand the basics of the Web.