# How to access `ServletContext` from within a Vaadin 14 app?

Tags: servlets, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am asking the same as the Question, [*How to access `ServletContext` from within a Vaadin 7 app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27933599/642706), but for Vaadin 14.

In Vaadin 7, Vaadin provided the simple and handy call:

```
ServletContext servletContext = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext();
```

That particular call is no longer there on [`VaadinServlet`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServlet.html) in Vaadin 14.

➥ Is there an equivalent somewhere else in the Vaadin API?

My end goal is to use the key-value "attribute" collection to keep references to my app-wide objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Methods still there, but not documented

Both methods:

- [`VaadinServlet.getCurrent()`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServlet.html#getCurrent--) ➙ [`VaadinServlet`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServlet.html)
- `VaadinServlet::getServletContext()` ➙ [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

…are there still in Vaadin 14.

It seems the second method, `VaadinServlet::getServletContext()`, isn't listed in the Javadocs because it's inherited from [`javax.servlet.GenericServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) and the Javadoc generation is run in a way that doesn't have access to that class.

Answer (score 1):

## `VaadinContext`

For the particular case of accessing attributes from `ServletContext`, there's a new [`VaadinContext`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html) abstraction introduced in Vaadin 14. It's added to make it possible for framework internals to access context attributes without being tied to the Servlet API. It can be accessed using `VaadinService.getCurrent().getContext()`.

[`VaadinContext`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html) can track attributes by their class:

- [`getAttribute(Class<T> type)`](http://getAttribute(Class%3CT%3E%20type))
- [`setAttribute(T value)`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html#setAttribute-T-)
- [`removeAttribute(Class<?> clazz)`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.4/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinContext.html#removeAttribute-java.lang.Class-)

Answer (score 0):

Update: One of the [Answers by Leif Åstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59627141/642706) explains both methods are actually present in Vaadin 14 but one is undocumented.

I verified that we can indeed call:

```
ServletContext servletContext = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext();
```

So the rest of my Answer here is obsolete. I will leave my Answer as a curiosity, rather than delete it.

---

This may not be the best way, but it seems to be working for me.

The [`VaadinServletService`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServletService.html) class, extending [`com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinService.html), offers the [`getCurrentServletRequest()`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServletService.html#getCurrentServletRequest--). That method returns a [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object. For there we can call [`javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext--) to return the [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) you desire.

```
ServletContext servletContext = 
        VaadinServletService            // com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletService
        .getCurrentServletRequest()     // Returns a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        .getServletContext()            // Returns a `javax.servlet.ServletContext`. 
;
```

From there you can use the key-value "attribute" collection as you mentioned. Look to the `setAttribute`, `getAttribute`, and `removeAttribute` methods with a `String` object as the key and a `Object` as the value.

Saving.

```
DataSource dataSource = … ; 
VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getServletContext().setAttribute( "javax.sql.DataSource" , dataSource ) ;
```

Retrieving. The key-value collection of "attributes" keep the value as an `Object`, so we must cast back to the expected class/interface.

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getServletContext().getAttribute( "javax.sql.DataSource" ) ;
```