# JPAContainer connection?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm learning JPAContainer, and I can't understand how to configure my SGBD connection...Using DAO mode I create an class that return my connection.

```
//ConnectionFactory DAO mode
public class ConnectionFactory {
    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21", "root", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How to create connection for to use with JPAContainer ? What better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start define your jpa persistence unit, lets say "addressbook". Then you could create a new JPAContainer using the `JPAContainerFactory`.

Example:

```
JPAContainerFactory.make(Person.class, JpaAddressbookApplication.PERSISTENCE_UNIT); // where PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "addressbook"
```

Going this way you don't have to deal with the `EntityManager`.

I highly recommend you to follow up [this](http://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/) tutorial and have a look at the following answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876743

Comment: but to configure my connection I need of eclipselink ? These examples http://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/ are using EclipseLink, but I don't know how to configure that. I'm so lost :/

Comment: @FernandoPaiva Well I see that you don't have much knowledge about JPA. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html